# PHP SimpleXML parse file, getting only a string

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

Yesterday I had already a question to parsing an xml document in php. Now the parsing works kind of, but I only get everything in a string, not an object.

My code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
debug($xml); // debug from CakePHP
```

Empty output, as I learned from my last post:

[image]

```
$xml = $xml->asXML();
debug($xml);
```

Now I only get the output as following:

[image]

I do get the XML code, but everything in a string with `->asXML()`. How can I get everything as a XML object? I tried to use the string with `simplexml_load_string($xml);` but that just outputs the same as in the first screenshot.

Maybe there is a problem because the XML starts with `<asx:abap></asx>` (namespace)?

If you want, I can upload my XML so you can test it.

**Edit 1**

I realized, that the first two elements in my XML are namespaced (`<asx:abap>` and `asx:values`). As soon as I renamed them to `asx` only, everything worked fine.

**Edit 2**

Here my XML for you to test.

[Downloadlink to XML](http://expirebox.com/download/5efa4790542a2fadcc7b3c5cbf3dfedd.html)

Comment: Indeed. The file won't be parsed correctly because the first element is namespaced. As soon as I replaced `<asx:abap></asx:abap>` with `<asx></asx>`, I get everything as an object. How can I fix that? The XMLs are generated by SAP and search/replace before parsing is not really a nice thing.

Comment: add your xml to the post

Comment: Can't replicate. Upload example minimal XML that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Uploaded the XML, it's in the post.

Comment: You have the right object - you can see that, because your debug starts `object(SimpleXMLElement)` - you just don't have the right debug function to view it - it looks like it's based on `print_r`, which doesn't know how to display SimpleXMLElement objects properly. Try https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug

Comment: And yes, `asXML` returns a string; that's it's job. Think of it as the reverse of parsing the XML string you received in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Your test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<rss> 
  <channel> 
    <item> 
        <title><![CDATA[Tom & Jerry]]></title> 
    </item> 
  </channel> 
</rss>
```

To load xml form file use following fucntion

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

 // echo does the casting for you 
echo $xml->channel->item->title; 

// but vardump (or print_r) not! 
var_dump($xml->channel->item->title); 

// so cast the SimpleXML Element to 'string' solve this issue 
var_dump((string) $xml->channel->item->title);
```

for more info see on this link
http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: I believe he doesn't need strings, he clearly said it is in string and he wants it in object.

Comment: @ArrowHead The OP wanted to access the XML as an object; this shows how. The string the OP didn't want was `->asXML()`, which turns *the whole object* back into the string it was just parsed from. However, it is a little more complicated than this example, because it uses namespaces, and therefore needs an appropriate call to [the `->children()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php).